# Javascript, table and array. tricky issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a bookshop website (for a little college javascript project) So far all my book info is in arrays in a .js file which looks like this..

```
var headings  = new Array(4);
headings [0] = "title"
headings [1] = "author"
headings [2] = "cat"
headings [3] = "bookid"
headings [4] = "cost"

var bookid   = new Array(6);
var title   = new Array(6);
var cat  = new Array(6);
var author  = new Array(6);
var cost  = new Array(6);
var desc  = new Array(6);

bookid [0] = "0001"
title [0]    = "For whom the tell bowls";
cat[0]   = "fiction";
author[0]   = "John Doe";
cost[0]   = "&euro;12.99";
desc[0]   = "This book is frickin' amazing blah blah blah"
```

and so on... there are 7 books...

Now I want to generate a table when I click on a thumbnail pic which has the author, title, cost etc. in one column and the actual corresponding details in the other column, Heres the code

```
for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                row = document.createElement("tr");

                // Each with 2 cells
                for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                    var cell = document.createElement("td");

                    var temp = headings[j];
                    var temp2 = (temp + '[' + filename + ']');
                    if (i==1)
                    {var text = document.createTextNode(temp2);
                    }
                    else 
                    {var text = document.createTextNode(temp);}
```

btw "filename" is passed to this function and it is the #of the book, eg, 0, 1, 2 and so on...
Now,  what displays on the page is sorta correct.. for book 0 I get..

```
title   title[0]
author  author[0]
cat         cat[0]
bookid  bookid[0]
cost    cost[0]
```

and for book 1 I get

```
title   title[1]
author  author[1]
cat         cat[1]
bookid  bookid[1]
cost    cost[1]
```

and so on, but details are not being interpreted as actual variables in an array. I'm guessing the solution has something to do with "innerHTML" or maybe casting my variables in some way..

If someone knows the solution to this it would be greatly appreciated!.. I'm planning to get this site finished today and move onto to something else more important (as this project is not worth many marks) But leaving this flaw in there would bug me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're tackling this problem right now is (trying to) access a variable by its name, e.g. you want to use `"title"` to find the variable named `title`. **Do not do this.** You'll either end up polluting the global scope and relying on `window` to access those variables, or you'll fall in the hand of the **`eval` devil**.

Here's a better idea: make objects to store your books. A book would then look like:

```
var book = {
    title: "Foo",
    author: "Bar",
    cat: "Baz",
    bookid: 123456,
    cost: "One hundred billion dollars"
};
```

Even better would be to define a type of books:

```
function Book(title, author, cat, bookid, cost) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.cat = cat;
    this.bookid = bookid;
    this.cost = cost;
}
var book = new Book("Foo", "Bar", "Baz", 123456, "One hundred billion dollars");
```

You could store these books into a single book array:

```
var books = [book1, book2, book3, ...];
```

and suddenly, it becomes easy to make a table!

```
// Create or get a table
var table = document.createElement("table");

// Loop over the books array
for (var i=0, l=books.length; i < l; ++i) {
    // Get the current book
    var book = books[i];

    // Create a table row
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    // Loop over the *properties* of the book
    for (var propertyName in book) {
        // Skip inherited properties
        if(!book.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) continue;

        // Get the *property value*
        var property = book[propertyName];

        // Create a table cell and append to the row
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(property);
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.appendChild(textNode);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    // Append the row to the table
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

You could even create the table headings using one book element:

```
// Some book to loop over its property names
var someBook = books[0];

var row = document.createElement("tr");
// Loop over the book properties
for(var propertyName in someBook) {
    // Now placing the *property name* in a text node
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(propertyName);
    var header = document.createElement("th");
    cell.appendChild(textNode);
    row.appendChild(header);
}
table.appendChild(row);
```

#### Update: Better control over the headings

As Dennis suggested, you probably want more control over the headings. You don't want to display `"cat"` as the heading for the book's category, you want something more readable. Also, you probably don't want to display all properties stored on a book object. In this case, you could store the headings to display in another object and add some more information about those headings:

```
var headings = {
    title: {
        text: "Book title"
    },
    author: {
        text: "Author"
    },
    cat: {
        text: "Category"
    },
    bookid: {
        text: "ID"
    },
    cost: {
        text: "Price"
    }
};
```

In your data loop, you would then iterate over the properties of `headings` instead of `book`.

```
// Loop over the properties to display
for (var propertyName in headings) {
    // Get the property value
    var property = book[propertyName];

    // [snipped]
}
```

In your headings loop, you would use `headings[propertyName].text` as display name instead of just `propertyName`. You won't need a book instance any longer, so the `someBook` variable can be removed.

```
// Loop over the book properties
for(var propertyName in headings) {
    var headingName = headings[propertyName].text;
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(headingName);

    // [snipped]
}
```

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, but keeping headings in a separate array is a better approach than `for...in`.  It gives the programmer far more control over the order in which the fields are displayed and avoids any inconsistency when enumerating the keys.

Comment: Good point. As an additional bonus, you could store metadata about those fields such as a readable name along with the property names.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
var temp2 = (temp + '[' + filename + ']');
```

You are concatenating strings; instead of the JavaScript statement `title[1]`, you end up with the string `"title[1]"`.

What you should do is create an object using a constructor function and build an array of objects instead of maintaining several [parallel arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array):

```
function Book(title, author, cat, id, cost) {
    this.title = title;  //for each variable
}

var arrayOfBooks = [];
arrayOfBooks.push( new Book( "The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "Fiction", 1, 5000.00));
//and so on for each book.
```

When you build your table:

```
var book = arrayOfBooks[filename];
var temp = headings[j];
var temp2 = book[temp]; //Use brackets instead of concatenating strings.
```

Another tip: the inner loop is unnecessary if you are just toggling with an if statement anyway.  You could just create two cells and put the necessary text values in each.